# Angular2: How to realise content progressive loading when scrolling?

Tags: angular

How to realise progressive loading of the page like this:

```
<section>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of postList>
      <post-item [post]="post"></post-item>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: do you want to track `ngFor` complete method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PrimeNG DataScroller http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datascroller/infinite

Comment: I've just found this: https://github.com/orizens/angular2-infinite-scroll.
What would be the better choice from your point of view?